# Como obtengo el total de elementos "completed" iguales a true y los datos "completed" iguales a false?

Tags: javascript

```
var lista2 = [{
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "delectus aut autem",
    "completed": false
},
{
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "quis ut nam facilis et officia qui",
    "completed": false
},
{
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 3,
    "title": "fugiat veniam minus",
    "completed": false
},
{
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 4,
    "title": "et porro tempora",
    "completed": true
},
{
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 5,
    "title": "laboriosam mollitia et enim quasi adipisci quia provident illum",
    "completed": false
},
```

son un total de 200 datos, necesito convertir el total en numero para restar el total de "true" con "false".

Despues debo sacar:

Res = (Total iguales a true - total iguales a false);
Total =(Total iguales a true * Res)*(largo lista/ Total iguales a false)

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza la función reduce, propia de los Arrays. Los parámetros usados son:
un callback (la función que recibe cada elemento del array e incrementa el contador)
un valor inicial (cero):

```
var lista2 = [{
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "delectus aut autem",
    "completed": false
},
{
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "quis ut nam facilis et officia qui",
    "completed": false
},
{
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 3,
    "title": "fugiat veniam minus",
    "completed": false
},
{
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 4,
    "title": "et porro tempora",
    "completed": true
},
{
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 5,
    "title": "laboriosam mollitia et enim quasi adipisci quia provident illum",
    "completed": false
}];

var totalTrue= lista2.reduce(  function(contador, registro){
              if( registro.completed) return contador+1;
        else return contador;
              } , 0);

var totalFalse= lista2.reduce(  function(contador, registro){
              if( ! registro.completed) return contador+1;
        else return contador;
              } , 0);

console.log( totalTrue, totalFalse);
```

Comment: Podrías ahorrar trabajo y un poco de líneas de código usando reduce solo una vez para calcular el total con true o el total con false. Luego el otro tanto haciendo una simple operación aritmética, p. e.: `const totalFalse = lista2.length - totalTrue`. Y si quieres reducir un poco más las líneas de código, puedes usar arrow functions y hacerlo en una línea `const totalTrue = lista2.reduce((contador, registro) => registro.completed ? contador + 1 : contador, 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

no esta muy claro lo que pides, intuyo que sera algo asi:
con esto puedes determinar cuantos false y true hay en el arreglo:

```
let falsos = 0, verdaderos = 0;

lista2.forEach(el => el.completed ? verdaderos ++ : falsos ++);
console.log("true: " + verdaderos,"False: " + falsos)
```

lo que hace es recorrer con el foreach todos los elementos del arreglo y con un operador ternario (lo mismo si fuese con if´s) evalua la propiedad completed, si es falso le suma 1 unidad a falsos y lo contrario a verdaderos. Luego tu puedes hacer lo demas con el resultado